# How to Implement Cross-Session Request Locking.

Tags: grails

I have a Grails application that executes to API calls, gets the reply, processes the data within the reply and then displays some charts and tables ion a results page.

The user enters some data and clicks a button to execute. So without any locking implemented if two users click that button at or near the same time what happens is that either one or both could wind up with no results being charted on the results page. I need to prevent this from happeneing, preferably by making the second request wait until the grails executes the first request.

I've read about optimistic vs. pessimistic locking but nothing really explains HOW to implement it and where. In the controller? In the service?

Is it a call like this and where?

```
 myInstance.save flush:true, failOnError: true
```

Any help understanding this is appreciated I couldn't find a whole lot of information out there about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement cross-session request locking.

The easiest way to do it is having a singleton map to prevent parallel execution of requests. That might look like:

```
class LockingSomethingController {
  static scope = "singleton"

  Map locks = new ConcurrentHashMap()

  def lockMe( String id ) {
    if( locks[ id ] ){
      render status:400, text:'locked'
      return
    }
    locks[ id ] = true
    try{
      doSomeSeriousStuff()
    }finally{
      locks.remove id
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay I imported import java.util.concurrent. I added this into the method that handles the execution of the api transactions, it didn't seem to do anything so I must be doing something wrong. I assume id is some unique strong like a sysId, I'm using myInstance.id.

Comment: `id` should be the id of your resource you are trying to lock. It might be some domain object's id, or a static name for the action, if the later should be executed exclusively. If you need to lock a single resource, you can replace the `ConcurrentHashMap` with `AtomicBoolean`

Comment: Is this in the controller or the service?

Comment: up to you. if it remains simple, leave it in the controller, when it gets more complicated and should be reused, move it to the service

Comment: You want only for that make controller as singleton, I don't think that it's a good solution, better to export logic into service.

Comment: This isn't working for me. locks[id] increments but the check is never true. If locks is a map don't I need to check every id not just what the "current" one is?

Comment: you have to remove that key from the map after your processing is over

Comment: Okay the lock is getting set & released, the only problem seems to be the check to see if the lock is actually set.

Comment: if you use the same key, it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: your solution's imperfect. another thread could still `doSomeSeriousStuff()`; if the system's heavy loaded and another thread checks for locks before the first thread actually call `locks[ id ] = true`. using controllers as singletons is also bad design idea.